# Building gcc 8.3 [Makefile:955: all] Error 2

Tags: 20.04, gcc, make

I've been trying to build a specific version of GCC (8.3.0) on a new Ubuntu 20.04 machine. However, when I follow the steps at the following link: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC I run into a Makefile error.

Steps:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-8.3.0/gcc-8.3.0.tar.xz
tar xf gcc-8.3.0.tar.xz
cd gcc-8.3.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd .. ; mkdir build ; cd build
../gcc-8.3.0/configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-8.3 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib
```

Config output:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for libmpx support... yes
checking for libhsail-rt support... yes
checking for gcc... gcc-7
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc-7 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc-7 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++-7 accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... yes
checking for gnatbind... no
checking for gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
configure: WARNING: using in-tree isl, disabling version check
*** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
     gnattools gotools target-libada target-libhsail-rt target-libgo target-libffi target-libobjc target-liboffloadmic
    (Any other directories should still work fine.)
checking for default BUILD_CONFIG... bootstrap-debug
checking for --enable-vtable-verify... no
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for yacc... no
checking for bison... no
checking for gm4... no
checking for gnum4... no
checking for m4... no
checking for flex... no
checking for lex... no
checking for flex... no
checking for makeinfo... no
/home/ubuntu/gcc-8.3.0/missing: 81: makeinfo: not found
checking for expect... expect
checking for runtest... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for cc... cc
checking for c++... c++
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for gfortran... no
checking for gccgo... no
checking for ar... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... no
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... no
checking for dlltool... no
checking for ld... no
checking for ld... ld
checking for lipo... no
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for objcopy... no
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for objdump... no
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for readelf... no
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for windres... no
checking for windmc... no
checking for windmc... no
checking where to find the target ar... host tool
checking where to find the target as... host tool
checking where to find the target cc... just compiled
checking where to find the target c++... just compiled
checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++... just compiled
checking where to find the target dlltool... host tool
checking where to find the target gcc... just compiled
checking where to find the target gfortran... just compiled
checking where to find the target gccgo... host tool
checking where to find the target ld... host tool
checking where to find the target lipo... host tool
checking where to find the target nm... host tool
checking where to find the target objcopy... host tool
checking where to find the target objdump... host tool
checking where to find the target ranlib... host tool
checking where to find the target readelf... host tool
checking where to find the target strip... host tool
checking where to find the target windres... host tool
checking where to find the target windmc... host tool
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
```

Then finally, using `make -j 8`, and sifting through the enormous output, I get the following error:

```
make -j8
...
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile /home/ubuntu/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/ubuntu/build/./gcc/ -B/opt/gcc-8.3/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/opt/gcc-8.3/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /opt/gcc-8.3/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /opt/gcc-8.3/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include    -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../../../gcc-8.3.0/libatomic/config/x86 -I../../../gcc-8.3.0/libatomic/config/posix -I../../../gcc-8.3.0/libatomic -I.    -Wall -Werror   -pthread -g -O2 -MT fior_8_.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/fior_8_.lo.Ppo -DN=8  -c -o fior_8_.lo ../../../gcc-8.3.0/libatomic/fior_n.c
In file included from ../../../../gcc-8.3.0/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:193:
../../../../gcc-8.3.0/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_internal_defs.h:317:72: error: size of array 'assertion_failed__1152' is negative
     typedef char IMPL_PASTE(assertion_failed_##_, line)[2*(int)(pred)-1]
                                                                        ^
...
make: *** [Makefile:955: all] Error 2
```

Any ideas? I've also tried configuring with CC=gcc-7 and CXX=g++-7 enviro variables and received the same result (it still uses xgcc). This seems to be an error with the cross compiler xgcc.

I've also tried with adding `--disable-werror` with no luck

Comment: Will [gcc-8*.4*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&searchon=names&keywords=gcc-8) suite your needs?

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be 8.3..

Comment: I think this is related with the kernel version (5.6.18) . Even though, I switched to Fedora 32 , I am facing the same error.